# Why doesn't pandas correctly pretty print my DataFrame with long MultiIndex level names?

Tags: pandas, terminal, pretty-print

pandas has a lot of magic in it to pretty print DataFrames based on the size of the terminal window. Unfortunately mine seems to be slightly miscalibrated, such that I often have to expand the terminal width by 1-2 characters in order to get it to fit. It's as if it's consistently underestimating the width of the MultiIndex, or overestimating the width of the terminal window.

As far as I can tell, the problem occurs when:

- There are too many columns to fit on the screen at once, and
- The index is a MultiIndex containing several levels with long names.

Here is an example script:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame(np.zeros((9, 16), dtype=np.int))
df.index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['awefawef', 'asdaoijo', 'awefoiasdfasji'], 
    ['awefawef', 'asdoaijo', 'awefoiji', ], 
    ])

print(df)
```

The result is ugly:
[image]

If I just slightly increase the width, it's fine. This is what I want: a subset of the columns, chosen not to exceed the available width.
[image]

But as I continue to work, I have to keep increasing the terminal width by 1-2 characters every few minutes, which is frustrating. So it's detecting that I'm increasing terminal width, but it still tends to make the output just slightly too wide.

I currently have these options set. These look right to me, from the documentation.

```
In [4]: pandas.get_option('display.width')
Out[4]: 80

In [5]: pandas.get_option('display.expand_frame_repr')
Out[5]: True

In [12]: pandas.get_option('display.pprint_nest_depth')
Out[12]: 3
```

Any tips??

Comment: Does `print(df.to_string())` help? Or what about `display(df)`?

Comment: @ALollz `print(df)` and `display(df)` produce the same result. `print(df.to_string())` prints the output without removing any columns at all, so it is very wide.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but I'm hoping someone will post a better answer.

If I set:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 12)
pandas.set_option('display.width', None)
```

Then the output is correctly formatted for the terminal width.

```
                         0   1   2   3   4   5   ...  10  11  \
awefawef       awefawef   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
asdaoijo       awefawef   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
awefoiasdfasji awefawef   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   

                         12  13  14  15  
awefawef       awefawef   0   0   0   0  
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0  
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0  
asdaoijo       awefawef   0   0   0   0  
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0  
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0  
awefoiasdfasji awefawef   0   0   0   0  
               asdoaijo   0   0   0   0  
               awefoiji   0   0   0   0  

[9 rows x 16 columns]
```

There are two drawbacks:

- I'd rather the number of columns be chosen based on the width of each column, rather than hardcoded as 12.
- This spills the output over multiple "frames", as necessary to get to 12 columns. I'd rather it be truncated with an "..." to fit all within one frame.

Nonetheless this workaround at least produces legible results. If someone can post a more full answer I'll accept it.